# Matlab Fspecial Filtering an Image

Tags: matlab

How can I use fspecial to apply an averaging filter to the image clown?

I have loaded the clown image into matlab and I have written h=fspecial('average', 3). Now how do I use h to apply the averaging filter to clown?

Answer (score 1):

You use the `avgImage = conv2(myImage,h)` function to perform a 2D convolution.

You might consider using `h=fspecial('gaussian',[5 5],1)` since gaussians give better blurring results, unless you specifically want to take the average.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to `fspecial`, that means you have the image processing toolbox.  I would recommend you use [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) instead, as it is specifically designed to filter images and takes advantages of [Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (IIPP)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp) if your processor supports it.  Very simply, do:

```
averageImage = imfilter(inputImage, h);
```

`inputImage` is the image you read in (presumably with `imread`), and `averageImage` is the output filtered image.